# MS Access - Syntax error on CREATE TABLE Statement in MySql - using Trigger

Tags: ms-access, syntax, triggers

For some reason, i can't get this to work..

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerupdate
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON ORDERDETAILS
AS
IF UPDATE(ORDERVALUE) BEGIN
        Print ('INSTEAD OF Trigger [triggerupdate] - Trigger executed!!')
        Print('You cannot update Order Value')
END
```

I'm trying to do a trigger if someone tries to update OrderValue.  IT kept saying that Syntax error on Create Table.

Let me know what I have wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify, your question mentions both "MS Access" and "MySQL" - but Access doesn't support triggers, and `Print()` isn't a function in SQL.

Comment: this class wants "Create an INSTEAD OF trigger to display the message "You cannot update Order Value", if a user tries to update the OrderValue field in the Order table." the example says this is correct...         CREATE TRIGGER triggerupdate
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON PERSONAL
AS
IF UPDATE(PERFORMANCE_ID)
BEGIN
Print ('INSTEAD OF Trigger [triggerupdate] - Trigger executed!!')
Print('You cannot update a Performance ID')
END                                                                  We are told to do this in MS Access yet I keep getting the error "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE Statement"

Comment: As Dai indicated, this SQL isn't compatible with MS Access. You should reconfirm which database system your class is using. Perhaps SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MS Access. Access does not support `TRIGGER`s, that's why you're getting Syntax errors, because "CREATE TRIGGER" is not supported SQL in Access.

Also, `Print` isn't a function in Access SQL either.

It's possible that you're meant to use Access as a front-end for MSSQL Server, which can be done, and where your SQL statements will become valid (but your use of `Print` is archaic).

Comment: like without it connecting to MySQL?

Comment: MSSQL, not MySQL. You cannot use Access to connect to MySQL, only MSSQL. You need an MSSQL Server first.